# add a period after all individual capitalized letters and groups of capitalized letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, how do I add a period after all individual capitalized letters and groups of capitalized letters?

For example:

- `John A Smith` should become `John A. Smith`
- `JRR Tolkien` should become `J.R.R. Tolkien`.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support look-behind.

Comment: ... and doesn't support `\h` character class.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your regex. It turns `aAA` into `aA.A.`, but `aA` into `aA` (no period).

Comment: Please define what exactly you mean by "individual capitalized letters and groups of capitalized letters".

Comment: @melpomene "John A Smith" becomes "John A. Smith" and "JRR Tolkein" becomes "J.R.R. Tolkein"

Comment: That's not a definition. I can do those with `txt.replace/[A-Z](?![^A-Z\s])/g, "$&.")`.